# Для чего нужен scanner при чтении?

Tags: golang

```
func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("test.txt")
 
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed opening file: %s", err)
    }
 
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)
    var txtlines []string
 
    for scanner.Scan() {
        txtlines = append(txtlines, scanner.Text())
    }
 
    file.Close()
 
    for _, eachline := range txtlines {
        fmt.Println(eachline)
    }
}
```

В чем разница с моим кодом :

```
args := os.Args[1:]
    f := args[0]

    file, err := os.Open(f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed opening file: %s", err)
    }

    result, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(file)

    defer file.Close()

    myFile := string(result)

    array := SplitWhiteSpaces(myFile)  // написал свою фунцкию для Split
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scanner позволил построчно считывать из файла, причем контролируя процесс.

Это полезно, когда файл слишком большой, чтобы считать его за раз, у вас может не хватить оперативной памяти